# resolve_error while comparing 3 securities

Tags: pine-script

I want to select what is best to trade among 3 pairs: 
ETHUSDT, BNBUSDT, BTCUSDT. 
However the code does not compile with error: resolve error

Thinking that the period is the problem I tried the code for different periods. There is no change. When I remove the plot of the result, the error disappears. However, I guess the compiler is optimizing and removing the problem code

```
//START OF STUDY
//@version=3
study("Trio Switcher", overlay=false)
Version=input(1)
// BNBBTC
bnbSwitch = close > nz(open[1]) //or close > close[1]

AltCoin = input("ETH")
alt_bnb_pair = AltCoin + "BNB"
alt_btc_pair = AltCoin + "BTC"

alt_bnb_ticker=heikinashi(tickerid(syminfo.prefix,alt_bnb_pair))
alt_btc_ticker=heikinashi(tickerid(syminfo.prefix,alt_btc_pair))

//BNB base
alt_bnb_open = security(alt_bnb_ticker, period, open)
alt_bnb_close = security(alt_bnb_ticker, period, close)

//BTC base
alt_btc_open = security(alt_btc_ticker, period, open)
alt_btc_close = security(alt_btc_ticker, period, close)

altSwitch = bnbSwitch ? alt_bnb_close > nz(alt_bnb_open[1]) :  alt_btc_close > nz(alt_btc_open[1])

ALTPAIR = 2
BNBPAIR = 1
BTCPAIR = 0

activePair = altSwitch ? ALTPAIR : bnbSwitch ? BNBPAIR : BTCPAIR

alertcondition(activePair==ALTPAIR, "ALT")
alertcondition(activePair==BNBPAIR, "BNB")
alertcondition(activePair==BTCPAIR, "BTC")

plot(activePair)
//END OF STUDY
```

When this indicator is added to a BNBBTC chart with a period of 1W, it should just plot 0, 1 or 2

Comment: I partially got the answer. The code is asking for ETHBNB and ETHBTC by default parameters. However ETHBNB does not exist. Instead BNBETH exists. So I guess specifying only the ETH part is not good enough...

Comment: So the real question is: Do I have to write a special code just for ETH while the other coins are ok? Is there a way to detect this in the code?

Comment: Why not just manually input all of the three tickers ? (like `ETHBTC, ETHUSD, ETHBNB`)

Comment: ETHBNB does not exist. So I have to enter "1/BNBETH". It does not work also. So the only remaining way is to add an option to say use the reverse pair and to change the calculation accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Pine 4 or 5. If returns true for crypto assets

```
isCryptoAsset = syminfo.type == 'crypto'
```